# how to remove value after comma(,) using vbscript and classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

i have two classic asp pages. from page1.asp, i pass value "userid" along with selected checkbox values in page2.asp by submitting form. but in page2, request.form("userid") value is repeating as request.form("checkbox") values count. For example userid value is 55 and if selected 3 checkbox then "userid" value is repeating 3 time like 55,55,55.

now i want to retrieve only userid as 55 and other values after comma (,) has to be removed.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `Split(userid, ",")(0)`

This will make an array of the elements seperated by a comma and takes the first element.

`Split(userid, ",", 1)` will do this right away.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx) for further info.

Comment: @lokeshpurohit: Please mark Barry's answer as correct if it is.

Comment: @lokeshpurohit :Please mark Barry's answer as correct if it is

Comment: @paul,Rafael i have marked the barry's answer...sorry for delay